# need help finding the coordinates of AB

Tags: polar-coordinates

Find AB if the coordinate of A is -5 and the coordinate of B is 17. i have been out of school for over 20 years and have little to no memory of this process. i examined my daughter's book and there is absolutely NO reference to this material at all. please help me understand how to solve this equation?

Comment: Conceivably you are being asked for the **distance** $AB$. In that case, the answer is $17-(-5)=22$.

Answer (score 2):

You want $B-A$, the distance from $-5$ to $17$

Answer (score -3):

The question is a little vague but I will answer what I think it means.  I am presuming A is a vector with coordinates (0, -5) and B is a vector with coordinates (0,17); equivalently they are the complex numbers -5i and 17i.  If you multiply them together you get (-5)(17)($i^2$) = 5x17.

For polar coordinates the angle (0, -5) makes with the x-axis is $-\pi/2$, so the polar coordinates of the endpoint are 5$e^{-i\pi/2}$.  For B the angle of (0,17) is $\pi/2$ and the polar coordinates of the endpoint are 17$e^{i\pi/2}$.

To multiply these two numbers together you multiply the 5 and 17, and add the exponents on the e which come out to 0. So you get 5 x 17 x $e^0$ which is 5x17.

It's a little harder when the angle isn't $\pm 90^o$, but perhaps that is another subject.

Comment: You're missing a factor of $i$ in the exponent of your polar expressions. More importantly, however, the question is almost certainly NOT about multiplication of complex numbers, so this answer is not helpful at all.

Comment: you are right about the i in the exponent -- I assure you that was inadvertent and I edited the post.  As to whether he was asking about multiplication or distance, I think it is not clear.  He wrote AB not $\frac{}{AB}$ and he tagged the question as "polar coordinates" which kind of implies multiplication.